# Having 2 multiline labels on single UITableViewCell in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a scenario in which a single `UITableViewCell` have 2 `UILable`. I can have long text in it coming from server which causes both labels to be multiline at same time.

I have implemented autolayout and

```
label.numberofline = 0;
tableVieww.estimatedRowHeight  = 100.0;
tableVieww.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

but it results only one label to expand not both. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please post your result screen shot?

Comment: Your solution looks fine! Do you have a vertical constraint between the two labels? and top constraint between the top label and its superview? and bottom constraint between the bottom label and its superview?

Comment: Do both labels habe numberofline set to zero?

Comment: Yes, both labels have numberOfLines set to 0 and I have added vertical height constraint between both labels. Top label has leading , trailing and top constraintand lower label had leading, trailing and bottom constraint  to content view of cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What You have so far looks fine. That should work without the need calculate the label height as some suggested.

Just make sure that you have the proper constraints on your labels.

1. Top constraint between the top label and its superview.
2. Bottom constraint between the bottom label and its superview.
3. A vertical spacing constraint between the two labels.

I tested it. it's working!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dynamicTableVuew.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    dynamicTableVuew.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId"];

    UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *label2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    label1.text = @"Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text";
    label2.text = @"Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text";

    return cell;
}
```

That's all I have in the view controller. and nothing special in storyboard.

**One last thing to check. Make sure that your tableview is connected to your view controller with an outlet. You may see the outlet code there but does not mean its connected. maybe it was removed by mistake.** the following lines will not take effect:

```
tableVieww.estimatedRowHeight  = 100.0;
tableVieww.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, both labels have numberOfLines set to 0 and I have added vertical height constraint between both labels. Top label has leading , trailing and top constraintand lower label had leading, trailing and bottom constraint to content view of cell. But still I can see only top label get multiple lines but lower label have one line ending with ......

Comment: check the upadted answer

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have followed all the instructions but can't get desired results. Can you please share any screenshot you got?

Comment: Also please let me know your labels Compression Resistance and Content Hugging.

Comment: The default on labels

Answer (score 3):

try this:

use this code to calculate row height

**Note : ExtraHeight"H"**

Suppose you have cell with height **100** and in that cell a label has height        **20** than extra height will be **80**, because this code is calculating the height of label as per text with its size.

you are going to put this code in **heightforRowatindexpath** so **cell.label** can't get there so just pass the text and use **Method-2**

**Method - 1:**

```
-(CGFloat)setRowHeightWithLabel:(UILabel *)lbl withLabelText:(NSString *)lblText withExtraHeight:(CGFloat)H withFont:(CGFloat)fontSize
{
   CGFloat totalHeight;
   CGFloat lblWidth = lbl.frame.size.width;

   CGSize lblTextSize = [lblText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(lblWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                           options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]} context:nil].size;

   if (lblTextSize.height > lbl.frame.size.height) {
    totalHeight = (lblTextSize.height+H);
   }
   else
   {
       totalHeight = lbl.frame.size.height+H;
   }

   NSLog(@"+++++++++++++Height - %.2f",totalHeight);

   return totalHeight;
}
```

Use this for use in **heightforRow** method

**Method - 2:**

```
-(CGFloat)setRowHeightWithLabelText:(NSString *)lblText withExtraHeight:(CGFloat)H withFont:(CGFloat)fontSize
  {
     CGFloat totalHeight;
     CGFloat lblWidth = 300;

     CGSize lblTextSize = [lblText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(lblWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                           options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]} context:nil].size;

    if (lblTextSize.height > 20) {
        totalHeight = (lblTextSize.height+H);
    }
    else
    {
        totalHeight = 20+H;
    }

    NSLog(@"+++++++++++++Height - %.2f",totalHeight);

    return totalHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using autolayout I had the same problem I resolved it by setting maximum width of labels and the in label's size Inspector you should set preferred width to your max width

[image: like this]

Answer (score -2):

If you want two labels to be multi-line (supposing you are using "Subtitle" cell type"), you must set numberOfLines to 0 to both labels, eg:

```
UITableViewCell cell = [UITableViewCell alloc]init];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Your lines about cell height seems to be correct